# Django: manipulating database with script; importation error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm going through the Django tutorial and wanted to try out database manipulating with a python script but encounter a problem

My script:

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
from django.utils import timezone
import numpy as np
#Questions
nquestions=3
q=np.empty([nquestions, 10], dtype=object)
qtext=q
qtext[0]="What's up?"
qtext[1]="What's new?"
qtext[2]="What's old?"

#Choices
q[0,1]="Not much"
q[0,2]="The sky"
q[1,1]="This question"
q[1,2]="This answer"
q[2,1]="No more originality"
q[2,2]="xxxxxxx"


#Check if exists and apply
for i in range(0, len(q)):
    q[i,0]=Question(question_text=qtext[i], pub_date=timezone.now())
    if Question.objects.filter(question_text=qtext[i]).exists():
        pass
    else:
        q[i,0].question_text=qtext[i]
        q[i,0].save()
        alen=len(q[i][q[i] != np.array(None)])
        for ii in range(0, alen-1):
            q[i,0].choice_set.create(choice_text=q[i,ii+1], votes=0)
```

I get the error django.core.exceptions.appregistrynotready apps aren't loaded yet. I'm running the script from terminal and it's places in the folder that contains the polls-folder (One level over modules.py, which I'm trying to import).

Writing the contents of my script works if i first run in terminal : python manage.py shell. Is there a way for me to run a script to manipulate the database through Djangos API, or do I have to enter information manually or send requests thŕough post?

Comment: Try running through the django shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable and call `django.setup()` before you can import your models.

```
import os
import django
# Change mysite if your project has a different name 
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()

from polls.models import Question, Choice
...
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) for more info.

Another option is to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). When you use `manage.py` to run your management command you don't have to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or call `django.setup()`.